# How to add to lists defined with c-lang-defconst?

Tags: list, c++11, emacs, cc-mode

I'm trying to add a C++ mode hook to add C++11 keywords to the appropriate keyword lists (which are defined in [lisp/progmodes/cc-langs.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/d40073f017ffb3dee2266f356c127ef587c40b71/lisp/progmodes/cc-langs.el) in the Emacs source code). As a minimal example, I started with `c-modifier-kwds` and tried adding the following to my .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-lang-defconst c-modifier-kwds
                             c++
                             (append '("thread_local" "noexcept")
                                     (c-lang-const c-modifier-kwds))))
          t)
```

(I copied the `c-lang-defconst` statement from [this C++11 mode implementation](https://github.com/roysc/cpp11-mode/blob/master/c%2B%2B11-mode.el). However, I don't want to create a whole new mode, I just want to add to the regular C++ mode.)

That didn't work (I didn't really expect it to, either). I also tried the following:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq (c-lang-defconst c-modifier-kwds)
                  (append '("thread_local" "noexcept")
                          (c-lang-const c-modifier-kwds))))
          t)
```

That didn't work either.

What's the right way to do this?

If there is no right way, what's a good hackish way to do this?

Comment: First, there is no need to quote `lambda`. Second, when you say "did not work", please explain what you mean - error? no effect? &c &c

Comment: @sds: Thanks for the tip about `lambda`. The new keywords are not highlighted is what I meant. There is no error.

Comment: `(setq (...) ...)` should signal a `wrong-type-argument` error. if you do not see that, it means that your code is _not_ executed. Note that modification of a hook take effect only when the hook is run, IOW, when the more is entered. Please try `M-x c++-mode` in a C++ buffer after modifying the hook.

Comment: @sds: Actually I realized that the `setq` does give me an error, I just failed to see it before moving the cursor (thereby hiding the error message).

Comment: Please start with setting `debug-on-error` to `t`.

Comment: @sds: I realized that I meant to put `setf`, but that doesn't work either.